# How to search for a string inside a file in Java?

Tags: java, file

Writing a java program and I need it to search one text file,personnel_addresses2.txt, for any cities names that contain the word Wax and then take the names of the people that live in those cities and search for those names in another text file, personnel_salaries2.txt, but right now its only returning the first result when there should be 13,586.

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class A
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
                File f1 =new File("personnel_addresses2.txt"); //Creation of File Descriptor for input file
                File f2 = new File("personnel_salaries2.txt");
                String[] words = null; //Intialize the word Array
                String[] salary = null;
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1); //Creation of File Reader object
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); //Creation of BufferedReader object
                FileReader f2r = new FileReader(f2);
                BufferedReader b2r = new BufferedReader(f2r);
                String s;
                String d;
                String Name;
                String City;
                String Person;
                String Sal;
                String input="Wax"; // Input word to be searched
                while((s= br.readLine())!=null) //Reading Content from the file
                {
                        words = s.split("\\|");
                        Name = words[0];
                        City = words[1];


                        for (String word : words)
                        {
                                if (word.equals(input)) //Search for the given word
                                {
                                        //list.add(Name);
                                        while((d = b2r.readL System.out.println(name);ine()) != null)
                                        {
                                                salary = d.split("\\|");
                                                Person = salary[0];
                                                Sal = salary[1];
                                                for (String sal : salary)
                                                {
                                                        if(sal.equals(Name))
                                                        {
                                                                System.out.println(d);
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }


                                }
                        }
                }
                fr.close();
                f2r.close();
```

personnel_addresses2.txt(partial)

```
Japheth Edwards|Albany
Evan Taylor|Wax
Olivia Grimme|Wax
Alfonso McNeil|Somerset
Allyson Schroeder|Washington
April Tomes|Lancaster
Laura Hancock|Louisville
Robert Joyce|Remington
HamedHaribHamed Yates|Somerset
Robin Snoke|Remington
David Bash|Versailles
Boyko Michels|Washington
```

personnel_salaries2.txt(partial)

```
Jessica Collett|59789
Mitchell Long|68985
Khumbo Benedict|53385
Adam Kandibanda|67671
Lloyd Wathen|98564
Daniel Towery|36588
Suzanne Siferd|97528
James Gudger|67113
```

Comment: `while((d = b2r.readL System.out.println(name);ine()) != null)` - This doesn't look like valid Java. It looks like you're only initializing your `BufferedReader` objects at the beginning of your method, even though you try to read the same file multiple times.

Comment: This is the ideal time to learn how a debugger works.

Comment: Does this compile? The version shown in your post would not compile.

Comment: contains "Wax" or should be equals to "Wax"?